# Left Mouse Click Not Work if Gui Follow The Mouse Pointer Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

**Left Mouse Click Not Work if Gui Follow The Mouse Pointer Autohotkey.**

i Have a Ahk Script that is able that my Gui with Picture Follow the Mouse Pointer.

But The Left Mouse Click does not work. (i can click/run notepad but i can not select Text in notepad!)

i do not now why it does do that? (the Gui+Picture is not on the Mouse Pointer.)

[image: gui follow mouse pointer]

Follow-Pointer.ahk

```
#SingleInstance force 
CoordMode, Mouse, screen 
CoordMode, ToolTip, screen 
IfNotExist, c5sc29f.gif ;c5sc29f.gif File is roket.gif 
   URLDownloadToFile, https://i.imgur.com/c5sc29f.gif, c5sc29f.gif 
Gui -Caption +LastFound +ToolWindow +AlwaysOnTop 
Gui, Margin, 0, 0 
Gui, Color, FFFFFF 
Gui, Add, Picture, x100 y100 w-1 h50 +BackgroundTrans, c5sc29f.gif ;
;WinSet, Transcolor, FFFFFF 
WinSet, ExStyle, +0x20  ; set click through style 
gosub, F1 
return 

F1:: SetTimer Draw, % (switch:= !switch) ? "20" : "-20" 

Draw: 
   MouseGetPos, x, y 
   y+=10, x+=10 
   If switch {
      Gui Show, x%x% y%y% 
      ;~ ToolTip,%  "x" x " y" y,% x+0,% y+50
   } else {
      Gui Cancel 
      ToolTip,
   }
return 

esc::ExitApp 
ExitApp

return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Gui Show, x%x% y%y% NoActivate
```

**NoActivate** avoids deactivating the currently active window.

Comment: Great it does Works, Thanks